# libnss_extrausers does not recognize user

Tags: debian, user-management

I tried setting up libnss_extrausers on debian jessie, but it does not work.

I installed it with: `apt-get install libnss-extrausers`
and changed /etc/nsswitch.conf to

```
passwd:         compat extrausers
group:          compat extrausers
shadow:         compat extrausers
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

In /var/lib/extrausers/passwd I inserted:

```
testuser:x:10001:10001:ExtraUser:/:/bin/false
```

But `getent passwd` does not list the user from /var/lib/extrausers/passwd
`su testuser` returns `No passwd entry for user 'testuser'`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Adding a blank line at the end of the passwd file makes getent passwd show the testuser, but su / ssh still does not work.